# Wheel click not working anymore

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, mouse

On chrome I use the wheel click either for fast scrolling or to open a new tab when clicking with it on a link.

However since a couple of days it's not working anymore but I didn't change anything so I don't know what could cause this issue.

I searched in `chrome://flags/` but did not find anything about it

Windows 10
Chrome version : 109.0.5414.120
Mouse : Razer Basilisk X hyperspeed (bluetooth connected)

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your mouse? Have you tried a different mouse?

Comment: I dont have an other mouse to test but yes i cleaned it. Also the wheel is properly functionning, it's just the click that is bugged

Comment: Yeah, so the little switch that is part of the wheel could be broken...

Comment: Do you know any software that could tell me if the wheel click is detected ? So I could know if this is the issue or if it's something else

Comment: Weel I found one (onlinemictest) and as you guessed it's the switch that is defective